# What can i use for rebuild user profile in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

On the user profile page in Drupal i need to add/edit folowing things:
1. Add few newest user articles
2. Add select with list all users. When another user is selected i`m redirect to his profile.
3. Completely rebuild the user profile template eg. i need to pack some fields in containers.

I need information what are the possibilities for the execution of those things. Should I use some ready-made modules (like views) or write my own from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really broad question, so maybe it's better to ask some seperate specific questions (on [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com)). However, I'll give you some hints underneath:

- The first two problems should be easily solved with the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.
- Take a look at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88407/how-to-create-a-profile-page. The [Panels](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwimgdS7v9LLAhVB_w4KHcZ2DM0QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Fpanels&usg=AFQjCNEImF_oYnUWgYMJGAPMYkzJKRjdeA&sig2=tK2OXRfoxGUxGu6SSVhMLw) module is real magic and it makes the theming you mentioned in your third question a lot easier.

Comment: I`m new in drupal and stackoverflow so all of your sugestions are very helpfull. Next time i will ask on drupal.stackexchange.com. Thank you.

Comment: @Equit: You're welcome. I understand that it isn't easy to find your way in the world of Drupal, but don't be intimidated. It really pays off in the end!

Comment: Yes you are right but after some time work with Drupal i can see that good programming skills are not required to build a website. Enough to have good knowledge of few modules. It is something weird for me because i'm usually deal with Magento.